# Why is my Caesar solution (CS50) double-typing uppercase characters?

Tags: c, cs50

My program can correctly encrypt lowercase letters, but for uppercase the output will double-type characters. For example, if I put the input in as "BARFOO", my program will output "EBDAURIFRORO". Code is shown below.

```
printf("ciphertext: ");
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plain); i < n; i++) 
{
    if (isalpha(plain[i]) && isupper(plain[i])) //problem must be here
    {
        int c = 65;
        printf("%c", (plain[i] - c + key) % 26 + c); 
    }
    
    if (isalpha(plain[i]) && islower(plain[i])) //this works
    {
        int c = 97;
        printf("%c", (plain[i] - c + key) % 26 + c);
    }
    
    else //this preserves punctuation, space, etc.
    {
        printf("%c", plain[i]);
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

What I'm trying to do in the first if loop is check for uppercase alphabetic characters. I then iterate over each character, converting it to an alphabetic index, where 'A' is indexed at [0], B at [1], and so on. At the end you can see that I convert it back to the Ascii index. Why is it doing this only with uppercase letters? Is my math wrong? For lowercase letters, the math is basically the same, but it's behaving as it should. I'm assuming it's a problem with my for loop, but I'm not sure what I have to do to change it.

Comment: Observe the `if` and `else` in your code. When will the `else` part execute?

Comment: @KamilCuk The else statement will execute if the input is not an alphabetic character. Inputting numbers, punctuation, etc. works as expected.

Comment: Your logical chain is broken. Hard to explain, but try an `else` before the second `if`, i.e. `else if (isalpha(plain[i]) && islower(plain[i])) //this works`. And no neither your "problem must be here" nor your "this works" is true. Sorry.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks, that fixed the problem. Should I always use an else statement before a second if statement, as you showed in your example? Or would that lead to more logical errors later?

Comment: @jaxk: Whether to use `else if` or simply `if` always depends on the situation, i.e. on the desired logic of your program. What do you want to happen if both `if` conditions are true? Should both conditional blocks be executed? Or only one? That is the question you must always ask yourself when you decide whether to use `else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first "if" is independent. So when input is uppercase, it will encode and show in the first "if", and then bypass and show in the "else" because it's not uppercase.

You can make the "else" just bypass every non-alpha characters instead of just bypass non-lowercase characters to solve this problem, like this:

```
printf("ciphertext: ");
for (int i = 0, n = strlen(plain); i < n; i++)
{
    if (isalpha(plain[i]))
    {
        if(isupper(plain[i])) //problem must be here
        {
            int c = 65;
            printf("%c", (plain[i] - c + key) % 26 + c);
        }else{
            int c = 97;
            printf("%c", (plain[i] - c + key) % 26 + c);
        }

    }else //this preserves punctuation, space, etc.
    {
        printf("%c", plain[i]);
    }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Or shorter: `int c = isupper(plain[i]) ? 65 : 97;` instead of the inner `if`-`else`-branch.